# How can I change global user.name and user.email in Git?

Tags: git, config

In order to discover and learn versioning with Git, I've created a global user.name and user.email. I want to change my global config informations (name and email). I didn't find anything to help me for now.

Comment: How did you find it the first time but not the second time?

Comment: Just as a test (to make sure I did not get asleep while falling in a spatial-temporal fault), I literally typed the title of your question in google and guess what...

Answer (score 1):

You can use below commands to change it :

```
git config --global user.name "FirstName LastName"
git config --global user.email "abc@gmail.com"
```

Comment: @ClaudeStrike If you'll run this command again with changed values it will overwrite the previous values.